# dojo chart2d columns plot prevent trailing zeroes after values

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

i have a dojo columns chart. Data is pulled from a rest service. Y values come as doubles, and X values come as integers. The problem is that dojo displays both values as doubles and i need both values to be displayed as integers.

For example,  if the X value is "1", dojo shows "1.0".

```js
function loadHist(objectId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/aquur/rest/getData/" + objectId,
  }).done(function(data) {

    /*
    sample data:
        
     data[0] = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0]
     data[1] =
     [Object { value=1,  text="1.0"}, Object { value=2,  text="2.0"}, Object { value=3,  text="3.0"}, Object { value=4,  text="4.0"}, Object { value=5,  text="5.0"}, Object { value=6,  text="6.0"}, Object { value=7,  text="7.0"}, Object { value=8,  text="8.0"}, Object { value=9,  text="9.0"}, Object { value=10,  text="10.0"}, Object { value=11,  text="11.0"}, Object { value=12,  text="12.0"}]
    */

    require(["dojox/charting/Chart2D", "dojox/charting/themes/MiamiNice", 'dojox/charting/plot2d/Columns'], function(Chart2D, MiamiNice, Columns) {

      dojo.empty("histogram");

      var chart = new Chart2D("histogram");

      var origCreateLabel = Columns.prototype.createLabel;

      Columns.prototype.createLabel = function(group, value, bbox, theme) {
        if (isNaN(value)) {
          origCreateLabel.apply(this, arguments);
        } else if (value > 0) {
          origCreateLabel.apply(this, arguments);
        }

      };

      chart.setTheme(MiamiNice);

      chart.addPlot("default", {
        type: "Columns",
        markers: true,
        labels: true,
        labelStyle: "outside",
        gap: 5
      });


      /*
      chart.addAxis("x", {labels: [
          {"value":0, "text":"6"},
          {"value":1, "text":"4"},
          {"value":2, "text":"5"},
          {"value":3, "text":"8"},
          {"value":4, "text":"6.5"},
          {"value":5, "text":"7"},
          {"value":6, "text":"9"},
          {"value":7, "text":"10"}x
      ]});*/

      chart.addAxis("x", {
        labels: data[1],
        title: "snakes",
        titleOrientation: "away"
      });


      chart.addAxis("y", {
        title: "apples",
        vertical: true,
        fixLower: "major",
        fixUpper: "major",
        min: 0,
        max: 100
      });
      chart.addSeries("Data", data[0]);
      chart.render();
    })
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="histogram" style="width:800px;height:400px;">
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide an extra of ```data``` as well as the full chart creation (the  ```new Chart``` the ```addPlot``` (if any), ... Best would be to use the snippets function of stackoverflow to create a working sample of your problem

Comment: @ben i've updated the question with the snippet. thanks for your help