# dojo contents appear briefly and then they disappear

Tags: dojo

I have this simple page that should display a bordercontainer with top, bottom and center regions. When you run it, contents briefly appear and then they disappear. Firebug shows no error and i can't see anything wrong with the code.

thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/esri/css/esri.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css">
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/"></script>    
    
    <script >
    var dojoConfig = {       
        parseOnLoad: true
    }
    
    require(
 ['dijit/layout/BorderContainer', 'dijit/layout/ContentPane',
 "dojo/parser", 
 "dojo/domReady!" ],  
 function(BorderContainer, ContentPane, parser) { 
  parser.parse();
 });
    
    </script>                      
    </head>

    <body class="claro" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;">            
 <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-  props="design:'headline',gutters:false" style="width:100%; height:100%;">          
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo- props="region:'top'">
      top
     </div>

     <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo- props="region:'bottom'">
      bottom
     </div>
     
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo- props="region:'center'">
      center
     </div>     
   </div>          
    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: regarding the actual code it seems to work. (At least when we run the snippet it works)... Maybe something else in your page is breaking it

Comment: strange! the code i posted is the very same i am running! thanks

Comment: I tried on chrome and firefox and its working....

Comment: @PrefijoSustantivo did you noticed you have unwanted spaces in your html ? You define "data-dojo- props" where it MUST be "data-dojo-props"

Comment: @ben those are because the formatting of this website when the line breaks. thanks for noticing anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research.
After fixing the unwanted spaces in "`data-dojo- props`" and replaced by "`data-dojo-props`" the same behavior as what you describe in your question arises.

Actually, it look like it is a sizing issue.

The border container will take the size of its parent. However, if it fail getting it. It size will be `0`, thus everything disappearing.

You see the content at first because the border container isn't loaded yet.
As soon as it gets loaded, the content is gone.

In the below snippets, I force the size of the `borderContainer`'s parent (the body tag in this example) to be `300px` by `150px`

The you can see that the content stays.

(Note: I also changed the `data-dojo-type` to use the slash notation. the dot notation is for old dojo version.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/esri/css/esri.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css">
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/"></script>    
    
    <script >
    var dojoConfig = {       
        parseOnLoad: true
    }
    
    require(
 ['dijit/layout/BorderContainer', 'dijit/layout/ContentPane',
 "dojo/parser", 
 "dojo/domReady!" ],  
 function(BorderContainer, ContentPane, parser) { 
  parser.parse();
 });
    
    </script>                      
    </head>

    <body class="claro" style="width:300px; height:150px" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px;">            
 <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline',gutters:false" style="width:100%; height:100%;">          
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">
      top
     </div>

     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'bottom'">
      bottom
     </div>
     
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">
      center
     </div>     
   </div>          
    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: thank you ben. it worked perfectly. i have a couple questions more about dojo posted, if you are interested... -easy points to be earned- hehe :)

Comment: @PrefijoSustantivo happy to help :) Is it old (already on stackoverflow) questions or new ones ?

Comment: this is the question that puzzles me. thanks for helping. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296023/dojo-chart2d-columns-plot-prevent-trailing-zeroes-after-values

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in below screenShot-

We are able to see contentPane however it shows a error for contents:

[image]

So I guess this weird behaviour may be happening because of content for these pane.

Try to add contents in it and see if you are getting same error or fixed in your environment.

Comment: very useful procedure. i always have a lot of trouble with dojo, by watching the server responses i believe things will get easier. thank you